# regex validation working on regex101 but not in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm using a regex that validates for an URL. The regex is:

```
^(https?|ftp)://\[^\\s/$.?#\].\[^\\s\]\*$
```

The issue that I'm getting is that when I check for the validation in regex101. My test cases are getting validated but in my JS code it's not validating the strings having an "s" in them.

https://regex101.com/r/Vy0MU0/1

This is the regex and the test cases that are working fine here but not working in my JS code.
I think the issue that I'm facing might be that the "S" characters are being treated as space.

```js
let DestinationRegex = new RegExp('^(https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s\/$.?#][^\s$]*$');
if (DestinationRegex.test("https://atlas.mapmyindia.com")) {
     console.log("Yeahhhhhhh")
} else {
     console.log("Nahhhhlh")
}
```

I tried this and always get into the else statement whenever I use the string with a `S` in it.

Comment: Constructing a regexp from a string works a little bit different than just pasting in the regex as string. It is simpler to use the literal syntax like so: `let DestinationRegex = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s\/$.?#][^\s$]*$/`. That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same regex directly in the if statement, it works.

Edit: saved regex in a variable instead of using it directly, for readability.

```js
let DestinationRegex = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s\/$.?#][^\s$]*$/;
if (DestinationRegex.test("https://atlas.mapmyindia.com")) {
  console.log("Yeahhhhhhh")
} else {
  console.log("Nahhhhlh")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, with conctructor it's a different syntax

```
let DestinationRegex= new RegExp(`(https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s\/$.?#][^\s$]`);
const str= "https://atlas.mapmyindia.com";
console.log(DestinationRegex.test("https://atlas.mapmyindia.com"))
if (DestinationRegex.test("https://atlas.mapmyindia.com")) {
  console.log("Yeahhhhhhh");
} else {
  console.log("Nahhhhlh");
}
```

Doc:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).